# Expose port to localhost url after running container from Shell script

Tags: image, shell, api, docker, containers

I'm new to Docker and have access an API that runs on a container.

I'm running a container via:

```
cp -r ./lib app/
docker-compose up -d --build app
rm -fr app/lib/*
```

In my docker-compose.yml I do have the ports set to:

```
 app:
build: ./app
container_name: my-app
ports:
- "9080:8080"
- "9990:9990"
- "6000:6000"
- "9877:9877"
- "1551:1551"
```

And a default ip for docker-machine: `192.168.99.100`

I should be able to send requests to an api via `https://192.168.99.100:8080/restapicall`

What am I missing? Is there any way to expose ports to localost in shell script?

Comment: Use localhost instead of that ip

Comment: Just to double check, is your container setup to accept SSL connections to port 8080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few observations.

- You are using wrong port number (8080) to access restapicall, In your docker-compose file, you are exposing port 8080 to 9080 (**- "9080:8080"**).
- Why are you using https? have you got SSL certificate set-up? if not try with http.
- 192.168.99.100 is this docker internal IP address? if yes then use your machine IP address or localhost?

Now try with below URL.

- Use localhost if you are running docker on the same machine.

  http://localhost:9080/restapicall
- Use machine ip address if Docker is running on different machine.

  http://machine-ip-address:9080/restapicall

If this doesn't work then please share your Docker file and docker-compose file.